# Codesign: The specified item could not be found in the keychain

Tags: keychain, certificate, code-signing

I am trying to codesign one VST plugin in Terminal. I added a self-signed certificate to the login keychain. I try to codesign using the following command:

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign Ozone\ 9\ Exciter.vst
```

However, I get the following error:
"*error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain*"

I even tried to force the identity by adding -s flag with my certficate's Common Name like this:

```
sudo codesign -s "Nikola Radosevic" --force --deep --sign Ozone\ 9\ Exciter.vst
```

However, I am still getting the same error